# C++ Getting neighbours of a cell in a grid, -1x throwing null exception when checked if != NULL

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, pointer-to-pointer, pointer-to-array

recently moved from C# to C++ so I'm new to pointers and references and so on.

I've a pointer-to-pointer array declared like this

```
enum Type
{
    Void,
    DeepWater,
    Water,
    ... etc }

Tile::Type** tiles;

TileManager::TileManager(int width, int height)
{
    this->tiles = new Tile::Type*[width];

    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
    {
        tiles[w] = new Tile::Type[height];

        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
        {
            tiles[w][h] = Tile::Type::Dirt;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm putting together a method that returns the neighbours of a cell in the tiles array and checking if each neighbour is not-equal to NULL.
However even when checking whether it's null or not seems to throw an error, so I'm stumped.

```
Tile::Type * TileManager::GetNeighbours(int x, int y)
{
    Tile::Type neighbours[8];

    if(tiles[x][y+1] != NULL)
        neighbours[0] = tiles[x    ][y + 1];

    ...etc

    if (tiles[x - 1][y - 1] != NULL)    //<-- Error fires here
        neighbours[5] = tiles[x - 1][y - 1];

    return neighbours;
}
```

I know why it's throwing the error but shy of checking X and Y to see if they go over the limit or below 0... I figure there's a more practical way to prevent this so thought I'd best ask.

Edit:

Thank you, user4581301. I found most of this code elsewhere and adapted it to reflect the changes you suggested.

```
std::array<Tile::Type, 8> TileManager::GetNeighbours(int c, int r)
{
    std::array<Tile::Type, 8> neighbours;

    const int y[] = { -1, -1, -1,  1, 1, 1,  0, 0 };// 8 shifts to neighbors
    const int x[] = { -1,  0,  1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1 };// used in functions 

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)// visit the 8 spaces around it
        if (inField(r + y[i], c + x[i]))
            neighbours[i] = tiles[r + y[i]][c + x[i]];
        else
            neighbours[i] = Tile::Type::Void;

    return neighbours;
}

bool TileManager::inField(int r, int c)
{
    if (r < 0 || r >= 25) return false;
    if (c < 0 || c >= 25) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should check if the indeces are out of bounds *before* accessing the elements. Also, `neighbours` is a local variable, it won't survive after the return.

Comment: *recently moved from C# to C++*  -- Use containers such as `std::vector` instead of raw pointers.  Using C++ doesn't mean you have to get into the weeds of pointers if you don't have to.

Comment: Anthony Please transfer the correct answer to Kaz's answer. Mine has tunnel vision on directly resolving the reported problem, while Kaz's answer, trading a bit of memory to avoid the issue completely, is the better solution for you and other future askers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tiles[x][y+1]`, if `y` is the maximum valid value, will not be `NULL` except by the grace of . This goes out of bounds and as soon as you go out of bounds all bets are off. You've invoked [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and pretty much anything can happen. Even what you expected to happen.

The same applies to the reported crash site, `tiles[x - 1][y - 1]`.

## Edit: Left out solution. Not helpful.

The only way, short of taking off and nuking the entire site from orbit, is to test the index to make sure it does not puncture the array bounds before using the index on the array. You'll probably want a function to handle this.

```
void assign_if(Type & neighbour, int x, int y)
{
    if(x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height)
    neighbour = tiles[x][y];
}
```

and call it

```
assign_if(neighbours[0], x, y+1);
```

and later

```
assign_if(neighbours[0], x-1, y-1);
```

## Edit: Stealing this from Bob__ for completeness

It is impossible to return a raw array from a function. The array goes out of scope and the pointer to it becomes invalid. Either pass in the array as another parameter or use a [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), both of which can be returned. Thanks to [Copy Elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization), a smart compiler will likely eliminate the copying costs.

Example:

```
std::array<Tile::Type, 8> TileManager::GetNeighbours(int x, int y)
{
    std::array<Tile::Type, 8> neighbours;
    ...
    return neighbours;
}
```

## Edit by original poster. Here is my solution:

```
std::array<Tile::Type, 8> TileManager::GetNeighbours(int c, int r)
{
    std::array<Tile::Type, 8> neighbours;

    const int y[] = { -1, -1, -1,  1, 1, 1,  0, 0 };// 8 shifts to neighbors
    const int x[] = { -1,  0,  1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1 };// used in functions 

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)// visit the 8 spaces around it
        if (inField(r + y[i], c + x[i]))
            neighbours[i] = tiles[r + y[i]][c + x[i]];
        else
            neighbours[i] = Tile::Type::Void;

    return neighbours;
}

bool TileManager::inField(int r, int c)
{
    if (r < 0 || r >= 25) return false;
    if (c < 0 || c >= 25) return false;
    return true;
}
```

## Edit: Caveat

This answer deals directly with solving the problem as asked. See the answer by Kaz for a description of a more practical solution that trades a bit of memory to completely eliminate the need for testing and generating the `neighbours` array.

Answer (score 2):

The more "practical" way (shorter code that avoids conditional checks) is to create the tile array so that it's it contains an additional "border" of tiles around the valid area. If any tile position  is in the valid area, then  is valid and so is .

You can have a special type for the border tiles which only they have, and simply include those tiles in the "neighbors" list. If your world has walls, then the border can consist of wall material.

Needless to say, you must never ask for the list of neighbors of a border tile. This is ensured by logic such as not allowing a border tile to be the valid position for anything.

This tile is in the valid area within the border" is a condition that is easier to check, in fewer places, and your program can be structured so that this check is actually just a removable assertion (a check for a situation that should not happen if the program is correct, rather than a check for an expected situation).

In C and C++, we can displace the pointers so that position `[0][0]` is still the corner of the valid area, yet the out-of-bounds coordinates `[-1][-1]` are valid indices, as are `[w][h]`.

Firstly, the column array is allocated two elements larger than necessary, and the pointer is the incremented by one.  Then the columns are allocated two elements larger, and each pointer is incremented by one before being assigned into the main array.

When freeing the arrays with `delete []`, you have to remember to decrement each pointer by one.